# Regexp capital words and exclude range

Tags: regex

What I am needing is this:

1. Match all capital `WORDS`
2. Match all word with the first letter `Capital`
3. Match all words with capital WORDS and dots between letters, like `F.M.I`
4. Include this letters `áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÑñ` in a word that succes point 1,2,3
5. Exclude a list of words with first letter Capital, like this: `En La El Los Ese`
6. Exclude a list of words with all letters capital, like `SALUD`

Comment: Could you please show us what you've tried? Thanks.

Those are some simple questions which can be googled. Just as some heads up:

All capitals: `/^[A-Z]+$/`

First letter capital: `/^[A-Z]/`

I would suggest you to research more for the rest.

Comment: I try this  preg_match_all("/(?!L[aAOo]s\b|Se\b|El\b|La\b|Lo\b|Los\b|Cierta\b|Ciertos\b|Ciertas\b|Poco\b|Poca\b|Pocos\b|Pocas\b|Cualquier\b|Cualquiera\b|Cualesquiera\b|Demasiado\b|Demasiada\b|Demasiados\b|Demasiadas\b|Tal\b|Tales\b|Escasos\b|Escasas\b|Tanto\b|Tanta\b|Tantos\b|Tantas\b|Cada\b|Todo\b|Toda\b|Todos\b|Todas\b|Más\b|Menos\b|Unos\b|Unas\b|Mucho\b|Muchas\b|Muchos\b|Un\b|De\b|En\b|Si\b)[A-Z][a-zA-ZÑÁÉÍÓÚáéíóúñ]+/", $titulo_copete, $match_todas);       but I cant exclude a word with all capital letters, like SALUD. Why and how can I do it?

Comment: **How** - As Naveed S has answered. :)
**Why** - I wish I knew.

Comment: @user2088434 Is F.á.M.I valid or not?

Answer (score 3):

`^(([A-Z](\.[A-Z])+)|([A-Z][A-Za-z]+))$` matches **first letter capital/all capital/capital letters separated by dot** words.

**What it does is**:

- `([A-Z](\.[A-Z])+)` matches a capital letter followed by one or more occurrence of the pattern **a dot followed by a capital letter** - 3rd requirement
- `([A-Z][A-Za-z]+)` matches a capital letter followed by one or more letters (to allow single capital letter also, replace + with *) - 1st and 2nd requirements

To allow the characters áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÑñ if the first letter is capital letter, just include these in the character class as

```
([A-Z][A-Za-záéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÑñ]+)
```

Inorder to exclude certain words you may use negative look ahead like

```
^(?!SALUD)(?!Los)(([A-Z](\.[A-Z])+)|([A-Z][A-Za-záéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÑñ]+))$
```

which avoids the words SALUD and Los.

- `(?!SALUD)` ensures the following character sequence is not **SALUD** and likewise is `(?!Los)`

I didn't get your fourth requirement well.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is good place to learn regex.

If you want to match regardless of the start and end remove the anchors.

Comment: Hi, its not a must that needs to start and end with that specifications.

Comment: @user2088434 then remove the anchors ^ and $

Comment: For example i have a line like this: En este dia SOLEADO en el M.S.P hubo Accidentes en la Salud. Pero la SALUD no fue problema.  From here I need to: exclude En and SALUD. i need to match: SOLEADO M.S.P Accidentes Salud Pero. With your example that doest work. Point 4 means that I can match a word like this NIÑO or Niño. Thanks

Comment: @user2088434 removing the anchors from the third regex may meet your requirement

Comment: like this? (?!SALUD)(?!Los)(([A-Z](\.[A-Z])+)|([A-Z][A-Za-z]+))

Comment: If i use that regex the word SALUD match ALUD and thats wrong for me. is the same problem that I have from the beggining :(

Comment: @user2088434 Considering SALUD to be excluded, of these, should any be matched? ASALUD , SALUDA and ASALUDA

Answer (score 0):

i think that this might work
\b(?!SALUD)(?!Los)((A-Z+)|([A-Z][A-Za-záéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÑñ]+))